# Unable to launch anything after changing hostname

Tags: process, hostname

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04, I have noticed that whenever I change my hostname by changing it in and with:

- `/etc/hostname`
- `/etc/hosts`
- `sudo hostname <new-hostname>`

Immediately after this, I can't open anything. Well, I can, but if I launch anything, the process launches, but just goes straight into a `Sleeping` state:

[image]

Although a restart will fix this, how come this is happening anyway?

The last command in the list should make it so that it changes without need for a restart, so why does my whole machine then mess up after running it, and then only allow a restart to resolve it?

**Information Update:**

Although it seems that I am able to switch to a TTY. But unable to actually create a new process without it going to sleep immediately and not launching.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: The same question with the correct accepted answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20612084/7869636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 15.04, in order to change hostname permanently you have to run this command:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname new-name
```

You can check directly your new configuration:

```
hostnamectl 

   Static hostname: new-name
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 458ad80036fa4cd4a3063116670ce33d
           Boot ID: 95a2349fc93f4d498bf189f0fc6fb858
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Ubuntu 15.04
            Kernel: Linux 3.19.0-21-generic
      Architecture: x86
```

Comment: This does not answer the question why launching applications does not work after changing hostname.